# Calculator App not working the way it should

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new here and just started learning python roughly 10 months ago. I am basically trying to practice in order to ensure what i have learnt does not escape me. Below is  the code i wrote for a calculator:

```
from tkinter import *


class Calculator(Frame):
"""Calculator class inherits from Frame Class"""

def __init__(self, master):  # constructs calculator App
    super().__init__(master)
    self.master.title("Calculator")
    self.master.configure(bg='teal')
    self.configure(bg='dark blue')
    self.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
    self.entry_text = StringVar()

    # Line of code below creates entry
    self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry_text,
                       font=('times new roman', 30))
    # set value for each button number
    self.btn1_var = IntVar()
    self.btn1_var.set('1')
    self.btn2_var = IntVar()
    self.btn2_var.set('2')
    self.btn3_var = IntVar()
    self.btn3_var.set('3')
    self.btn4_var = IntVar()
    self.btn4_var.set('4')
    self.btn5_var = IntVar()
    self.btn5_var.set('5')
    self.btn6_var = IntVar()
    self.btn6_var.set('6')
    self.btn7_var = IntVar()
    self.btn7_var.set('7')
    self.btn8_var = IntVar()
    self.btn8_var.set('8')
    self.btn9_var = IntVar()
    self.btn9_var.set('9')
    self.btn0_var = IntVar()
    self.btn0_var.set('0')

    # position entry widget in window
    self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=N + S + W + E)

    # create buttons for each number
    self.btn1 = Button(self, text='1', width=20, height=2, command=self.num1)
    self.btn1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.btn2 = Button(self, text='2', width=20, height=2, command=self.num2)
    self.btn2.grid(row=1, column=2)
    self.btn3 = Button(self, text='3', width=20, height=2, command=self.num3)
    self.btn3.grid(row=1, column=3)
    self.btn4 = Button(self, text='4', width=20, height=2, command=self.num4)
    self.btn4.grid(row=2, column=1)
    self.btn5 = Button(self, text='5', width=20, height=2, command=self.num5)
    self.btn5.grid(row=2, column=2)
    self.btn6 = Button(self, text='6', width=20, height=2, command=self.num6)
    self.btn6.grid(row=2, column=3)
    self.btn7 = Button(self, text='7', width=20, height=2, command=self.num7)
    self.btn7.grid(row=3, column=1)
    self.btn8 = Button(self, text='8', width=20, height=2, command=self.num8)
    self.btn8.grid(row=3, column=2)
    self.btn9 = Button(self, text='9', width=20, height=2, command=self.num9)
    self.btn9.grid(row=3, column=3)
    self.btn0 = Button(self, text='0', width=20, height=2, command=self.num0)
    self.btn0.grid(row=4, column=2)

    # create buttons for each arithmetic operation
    self.sub_btn = Button(self, text='-', width=20, height=2, command=self.subtract)
    self.sub_btn.grid(row=5, column=0)
    self.add_btn = Button(self, text='+', width=20, height=2, command=self.add)
    self.add_btn.grid(row=5, column=1)
    self.mul_btn = Button(self, text='*', width=20, height=2, command=self.multiply)
    self.mul_btn.grid(row=5, column=2)
    self.div_btn = Button(self, text='/', width=20, height=2, command=self.divide)
    self.div_btn.grid(row=5, column=3)
    self.eq_btn = Button(self, text='=', width=20, height=2, command=self.equals_to)
    self.eq_btn.grid(row=5, column=4)

# event handlers for arithmetic operations
def subtract(self):
    """include minus sign in entry"""
    self.entry.insert(END, '-')

def add(self):
    """include + sign in entry"""
    self.entry.insert(END, '+')

def divide(self):
    """include / sign in entry"""
    self.entry.insert(END, '/')

def multiply(self):
    """include * sign in entry"""
    self.entry.insert(END, '*')

def equals_to(self):
    """evaluate arithmetic expression in entry"""
    if self.entry_text.get() is '':
        self.entry_text.set('Ans=' + '0')
    elif 'Ans' in self.entry_text.get():
        self.entry_text.set(self.entry_text.get())
    elif self.entry_text.get()[0] == '0':
        self.entry_text.set('Ans=' + self.entry_text.get()[1:])
    else:
        self.entry_text.set('Ans=' + str(eval(self.entry_text.get())))

# event handlers for pressing a number(button number)
def num1(self):
    """include 1 in entry"""
    if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and ('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, 4)
    elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
    self.entry.insert(END, self.btn1_var.get())

def num2(self):
    """include 2 in entry"""
    if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and ('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, 4)
    elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
    self.entry.insert(END, self.btn2_var.get())

def num3(self):
    """include 3 in entry"""
    if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and ('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, 4)
    elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
    self.entry.insert(END, self.btn3_var.get())

def num4(self):
    """include 4 in entry"""
    if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and ('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, 4)
    elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
    self.entry.insert(END, self.btn4_var.get())

def num5(self):
    """include 5 in entry"""
    if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and ('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, 4)
    elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
    self.entry.insert(END, self.btn5_var.get())

def num6(self):
    """include 6 in entry"""
    if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and ('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, 4)
    elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
    self.entry.insert(END, self.btn6_var.get())

def num7(self):
    """include 7 in entry"""
    if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and ('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, 4)
    elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
    self.entry.insert(END, self.btn7_var.get())

def num8(self):
    """include 8 in entry"""
    if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and ('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, 4)
    elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
    self.entry.insert(END, self.btn8_var.get())

def num9(self):
    """include 9 in entry"""
    if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and ('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, 4)
    elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
    self.entry.insert(END, self.btn9_var.get())

def num0(self):
    """include 0 in entry"""
    if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and ('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, 4)
    elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
    self.entry.insert(END, self.btn0_var.get())


root = Tk()
Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to continue an arithmetic expression with the answer i get from a previous arithmetic expression on the calculator. It works but after like maybe the second try or i try to append more than one operand it kind of messes up leaving only the last number i typed. After if i append any arithmetic operator and try to append a number it clears everything else i wrote and leaves only the last number inputted. Would really appreciate assistance on this. Feel free to run the code and let me know what is wrong with it.

P.S. I know i could have used a for loop to construct buttons, i even did but was getting confused as associating the event handlers with the relevant buttons so just coding them line by line seemed like the best way to go for now....

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So sorry that my question did not meet recommendations. I think i have sorted it out though. My next question will be more up to par.

Comment: Please try to debug first and if debugging does not helps then ask on Stackoverflow. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what is going wrong.
The expression below causes the problem.

```
('-' or '+' or '*' or '/') in self.entry.get()
```

If you replace it with the below expression , your problem will be solved.

```
any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/'))
```

You should replace it for entire numbers.

Here I replaced them, ready to use :)

```
from tkinter import *


class Calculator(Frame):
    """Calculator class inherits from Frame Class"""

    def __init__(self, master):  # constructs calculator App
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.title("Calculator")
        self.master.configure(bg='teal')
        self.configure(bg='dark blue')
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        self.entry_text = StringVar()

        # Line of code below creates entry
        self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry_text,
                        font=('times new roman', 30))
        # set value for each button number
        self.btn1_var = IntVar()
        self.btn1_var.set('1')
        self.btn2_var = IntVar()
        self.btn2_var.set('2')
        self.btn3_var = IntVar()
        self.btn3_var.set('3')
        self.btn4_var = IntVar()
        self.btn4_var.set('4')
        self.btn5_var = IntVar()
        self.btn5_var.set('5')
        self.btn6_var = IntVar()
        self.btn6_var.set('6')
        self.btn7_var = IntVar()
        self.btn7_var.set('7')
        self.btn8_var = IntVar()
        self.btn8_var.set('8')
        self.btn9_var = IntVar()
        self.btn9_var.set('9')
        self.btn0_var = IntVar()
        self.btn0_var.set('0')

        # position entry widget in window
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=N + S + W + E)

        # create buttons for each number
        self.btn1 = Button(self, text='1', width=20, height=2, command=self.num1)
        self.btn1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.btn2 = Button(self, text='2', width=20, height=2, command=self.num2)
        self.btn2.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.btn3 = Button(self, text='3', width=20, height=2, command=self.num3)
        self.btn3.grid(row=1, column=3)
        self.btn4 = Button(self, text='4', width=20, height=2, command=self.num4)
        self.btn4.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.btn5 = Button(self, text='5', width=20, height=2, command=self.num5)
        self.btn5.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.btn6 = Button(self, text='6', width=20, height=2, command=self.num6)
        self.btn6.grid(row=2, column=3)
        self.btn7 = Button(self, text='7', width=20, height=2, command=self.num7)
        self.btn7.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.btn8 = Button(self, text='8', width=20, height=2, command=self.num8)
        self.btn8.grid(row=3, column=2)
        self.btn9 = Button(self, text='9', width=20, height=2, command=self.num9)
        self.btn9.grid(row=3, column=3)
        self.btn0 = Button(self, text='0', width=20, height=2, command=self.num0)
        self.btn0.grid(row=4, column=2)

        # create buttons for each arithmetic operation
        self.sub_btn = Button(self, text='-', width=20, height=2, command=self.subtract)
        self.sub_btn.grid(row=5, column=0)
        self.add_btn = Button(self, text='+', width=20, height=2, command=self.add)
        self.add_btn.grid(row=5, column=1)
        self.mul_btn = Button(self, text='*', width=20, height=2, command=self.multiply)
        self.mul_btn.grid(row=5, column=2)
        self.div_btn = Button(self, text='/', width=20, height=2, command=self.divide)
        self.div_btn.grid(row=5, column=3)
        self.eq_btn = Button(self, text='=', width=20, height=2, command=self.equals_to)
        self.eq_btn.grid(row=5, column=4)

    # event handlers for arithmetic operations
    def subtract(self):
        """include minus sign in entry"""
        self.entry.insert(END, '-')

    def add(self):
        """include + sign in entry"""
        self.entry.insert(END, '+')

    def divide(self):
        """include / sign in entry"""
        self.entry.insert(END, '/')

    def multiply(self):
        """include * sign in entry"""
        self.entry.insert(END, '*')

    def equals_to(self):
        """evaluate arithmetic expression in entry"""
        if self.entry_text.get() is '':
            self.entry_text.set('Ans=' + '0')
        elif 'Ans' in self.entry_text.get():
            self.entry_text.set(self.entry_text.get())
        elif self.entry_text.get()[0] == '0':
            self.entry_text.set('Ans=' + self.entry_text.get()[1:])
        else:
            self.entry_text.set('Ans=' + str(eval(self.entry_text.get())))

    # event handlers for pressing a number(button number)
    def num1(self):
        """include 1 in entry"""
        if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/')):
            self.entry.delete(0, 4)
        elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, self.btn1_var.get())

    def num2(self):
        """include 2 in entry"""
        if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/')):
            self.entry.delete(0, 4)
        elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, self.btn2_var.get())

    def num3(self):
        """include 3 in entry"""
        if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/')):
            self.entry.delete(0, 4)
        elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, self.btn3_var.get())

    def num4(self):
        """include 4 in entry"""
        if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/')):
            self.entry.delete(0, 4)
        elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, self.btn4_var.get())

    def num5(self):
        """include 5 in entry"""
        if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/')):
            self.entry.delete(0, 4)
        elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, self.btn5_var.get())

    def num6(self):
        """include 6 in entry"""
        if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/')):
            self.entry.delete(0, 4)
        elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, self.btn6_var.get())

    def num7(self):
        """include 7 in entry"""
        if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/')):
            self.entry.delete(0, 4)
        elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, self.btn7_var.get())

    def num8(self):
        """include 8 in entry"""
        if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/')):
            self.entry.delete(0, 4)
        elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, self.btn8_var.get())

    def num9(self):
        """include 9 in entry"""
        if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/')):
            self.entry.delete(0, 4)
        elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, self.btn9_var.get())

    def num0(self):
        """include 0 in entry"""
        if 'Ans=' in self.entry.get() and any(item in self.entry.get() for item in ('-', '+', '*', '/')):
            self.entry.delete(0, 4)
        elif 'Ans=' in self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, self.btn0_var.get())


root = Tk()
Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Let me explain myself.
You wanted to check if 'Ans' in the text and also sing in the text.
The first part of if condition works well. In the second part little bit tricky.

In python, tuples are comma-separated. `('-' or '+' or '*' or '/')` this will evaluate to '-' sing. Because you concat them with or condition. Result of this, you are checking only minus sign.

Comment: Thank you @ErdoganOnal. Really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome :) Can you please accept if my code works.

Comment: yes it does so far so good. I noticed the error i made in the expression before i saw your reply but the way you solved it is quite cool. I did not know there was a python key word like 'any'. Guess i learnt something today. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ErdoganOnal Sometimes people don't bother about the rep system here, they get their answer and they're done. Don't let it demotivate you, I've upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @ArdentCoder i really did not know i was meant to click on anything to show that i accepted his answer. I am new here but i just got a notification when i logged in and came to check on this my question that i am meant to actually click on the tick to show i accepted his answer...

Comment: My bad @ErdoganOnal.

Comment: @DammyD Haha no worries